# Silverlight application in Sharepoint - list permission issue

Tags: sharepoint, silverlight-4.0, permissions

I have Silverlight application set in Sharepoint webpart. The application modifies Sharepoint lists using client object model.

What I want to achieve is to provide some security for these lists. The idea is that users should be able to modify lists only by my application. Modifying by SharePoint UI shouldn’t be possible for users.

I know that something like that could be achieved using web services but my question is whether is it possible using client object model?

Thanks for any reply and sorry for my English.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The user will always have a context and be allowed to edit based on that logged in context and the list permissions.

You could try other tricks such as hiding the lists and adding controls for the edit/new forms that based on a user not being part of an admin group, simply refuse to show the list information in the normal manner but allow the list information through your Silverlight application.